# REGEX - Automatic text selection and restructering

Tags: regex, report, autohotkey

I am kinda new to AHK, I've written some scripts. But with my latest script, I'm kind of stuck with REGEX in AHK.
I want to make the report of a structure of texts I make.

To do this I've set up a system:

1. sentences ending on a '.', are the important sentences with "-". (variable 'Vimportant') BUT WITHOUT the words mentioned for 'Vanecdotes2' or 'Vdelete2' cfr. 4
2. sentences ending on a '.*', are the anecdotes (variable 'Vanecdotes1') where I've put a star manualy after the point.
3. sentences ending on a '.!', are irrelevant sentences and need to be deleted (variable 'Vdelete1') were I've put a star manually after the point.
4. an extra option I want to implement are words to detect in a sentence so that the sentence will be automatically added to the variable 'Vanecdotes2' or 'Vdelete2'

An random example would be this (I already have put ! and * after the sentence (why is not important) and of which "acquisition" is an example op Vanecdotes2 of my point 4 above):

Last procedure on 19/8/2019.

```
Normal structure x1.!  
Normal structure x2.!  
Abberant structure x3, needs follow-up within 2 months.  
Structure x4 is lower in activity, but still above p25.  
Abberant structure x4, needs follow-up within 6 weeks.  
Normal structure x5.  
Good aqcuisition of x6.
```

So the output of the Regex in the variables should be

```
Last procedure on 19/8/2019.  
Normal structure x1.! --> regex  '.!' --> Vdelete1  
Normal structure x2.! --> regex  '.!' --> Vdelete1  
Abberant structure x3, needs follow-up within 2 months. --> Regex '.' = Vimportant  
Structure x4 is lower in activity, but still above p25.* --> regex '.*' = Vanecdote1  
Abberant structure x4, needs follow-up within 6 weeks. --> Regex '.' = Vimportant  
Normal structure x5.! --> regex  '.!' --> Vdelete1  
Good aqcuisition of x6. --> Regex 'sentence with the word acquisition' = Vanecdote2
```

And the output should be:

```
'- Last procedure on 19/8/2019.  
 - Abberant structure x3, needs follow-up within 2 months.  
 - Abberant structure x4, needs follow-up within 6 weeks.  

. Structure x4 is lower inactivity, but still above p25.  
. Good aqcuisition of x6.
```

But I have been having a lot of trouble with the regex, especialy with the selection of sentences ending on a * or !. But also with the exclusion criteria, they just don't want to do it.

Because AHT doesn't have a real good tester, I first tested it in another regex tester and I was planning to 'translate' it later on to AHK code..  but it just doesn't work. (so I know in the script below I'm using AHK language with nonAHK regex, but I've just put the to together for illustration)

This is what i have now:

```
Send ^c  
clipwait, 1000  
Temp := Clipboard  
Regexmatch(Temp, "^.*[.]\n(?!^.*\(Anecdoteword1|Anecdoteword2|deletewordX|deletewordY)\b.*$)", Vimportant)  
Regexmatch(Temp, "^.*[.][*]\n")", Vanecdotes1) 
Regexmatch(Temp, "^.*[.][!]\n")", Vdelete1)   
Regexmatch(Temp, "^.*\b(Anecdoteword1|Anecdoteword2)\b.*$")", Vanecdotes2)  
Regexmatch(Temp, "^.*\b(deletewordX|deletewordY)\b.*$")", Vdelete2)   
Vanecdotes_tot := Vanecdotes1 . Vanecdotes2  
Vdelete_tot := Vdelete1 . Vdelete2  
Vanecdotes_ster := "* " . StrReplace(Vanecdotes_tot, "`r`n", "`r`n* ")  
Vimportant_stripe := "- " . StrReplace(Vimportant, "`r`n", "`r`n- ")  
Vresult := Vimportant_stripe . "`n`n" . Vanecdotes_ster
```

For "translation to AHK"  I tried to make `^.*\*'n` from the working (non ahk) regex `^.*[.][*]\n`.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't really such a thing as AHK regex. AHK pretty much uses PCRE, apart from the [options](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/misc/RegEx-QuickRef.htm#Options).
So don't try to turn a linefeed `\n` into an *AHK linefeed* `` `n ``.

And there seem to be some syntax errors in your regexes. Not quite sure what those extra `")` in there are supposed to be. Also, instead of using `[.][*]`, you're *supposed* to use `\.\*`. The `\` is required with those specific characters to escape their normal functionality (any character and match between zero and unlimited).
`[]` is to match any character in that group, like if you wanted to match either `.` or `*` you'd do `[.*]`.

And seems like you got the idea of using capture groups, but just in case, here's a minimal example about them:

```
RegexMatch("TestTest1233334Test", "(\d+)", capture)
MsgBox, % capture
```

And lastly, about your approach to the problem, I'd recommend looping through the input line by line. It'll be much better/easier. Use e.g [`LoopParse`](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/LoopParse.htm).
Minimal example for it as well:

```
inp := "
(
this is
a multiline
textblock
we're going
to loop
through it
line by line
)"

Loop, Parse, inp, `n, `r
    MsgBox, % "Line " A_Index ":`n" A_LoopField
```

Hope this was of help.

Comment: Sorry, i made some errors while copy-pasting (the ") was from copy pasting).  
I don't really get what you mean by "So don't try to turn a linefeed \n into an AHK linefeed `n". I can use \n for Regex in AHK? Then what is the difference between the two?  
I've been working on my Regex and now they work on the tester. (?=.*[.]\n)((?!Anecdoteword1|Anecdoteword2|deletewordX|deletewordY).)*$ so i will try to let it work in AHK.  
Thanks for the Loop tip, i will dig into it:)!

Answer (score 0):

This i were i al up till now, nothing works (i will try the suggested loop when Regex is working):  ^m::
BlockInput, On
MouseGetPos, , ,TempID, control
                WinActivate, ahk_id %TempID%
                if WinActive("Pt.")
                               Send ^c
                               clipwait, 1000
                               Temp := Clipboard
                               Regexmatch(Temp, "(^(?:.*.\n)((?! PAX|PAC|Normaal|Geen).)*$)", Vimportant)
                               Vimportant := Vimportant.1
                               Regexmatch(Temp, "(^.*.*\n)", Vanecdotes1_ster)
                               Regexmatch(Temp, "(^.*.!\n)" , Vdelete1_uitroep)
                               Regexmatch(Temp, "(^.*\b(PAX|PAC)\b.*$)", Vanecdotes2)
                               Regexmatch(Temp, "(^.*\b(Normaal|Geen)\b.*$)", Vdelete2)
                               Vanecdotes1 := StrReplace(Vanecdotes1_ster, ".*", ".")
                               Vdelete1 := StrReplace(Vdelete1_uitroep, ".!", ".")
                               Vanecdotes_tot := Vanecdotes1 . Vanecdotes2
                               Vdelete_tot := Vdelete1 . Vdelete2
                               Vanecdotes_ster := "* " . StrReplace(Vanecdotes_tot, "`r`n", "`r`n* ")
                               Vimportant_stripe := "- " . StrReplace(Vimportant, "`r`n", "`r`n- ")
                               Vresult := Vimportant_stripe . "`n`n" . Vanecdotes_ster
                               Clipboard := Vresult
                               Send ^v
return